# Can we show that this nonlocal 1D equation is solvable?

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, partial-differential-equations

The equation I have in mind is of the form
\begin{align*}
   \frac{d}{dx} v = H(fv),
\end{align*}
where every function involved is $2 \pi$-periodic, $f > 0$ and is as smooth as necessary and $H$ is a periodic Hilbert transform, i.e. 
\begin{align*}
   \widehat{H g} (n) = - i \text{ sgn}(n) \hat{g}(n).
\end{align*}
Is the above differential equation solvable?

Comment: The equation does seem underdetermined. If I understood correctly your notation, in the case $f\equiv 1$, via Fourier transform we obtain that $v$ is a solution if and only if $\hat v(n) = 0$ for $n\ge0$, with no restrictions whatsoever on $\hat v(n)$ if $n\ge 0$.

Comment: @DarioP. In that case, $i n \hat{v} (n) = - i \text{ sgn} (n) \hat{v}(n)$, hence $\hat{v}(n) = 0$ for all nonzero $n$. Of course I know that the zero mode can be chosen arbitrarily, but that is not important here. Let us additionally assume that the zero mode $\hat{v} (0) = 0$ always. Then the solution is unique in that case.

Comment: But $-\operatorname{sgn}(n)=1$ if $n<0$, so there are no constraints on $\hat v(n)$ for negative $n$. (There is a typo in the last inequality I wrote above, It should be $n\le 0$.)

Comment: @DarioP. I do not understand your comment. That gives $i n \hat{v} (n) = i \hat{v} (n)$ for all negative $n$ hence $\hat{v} (n) = 0$.

Comment: You are right, my mistake.

Comment: What is however true is that it is underdetermined as stated, and that the additional conditions you must impose depends on the function $f$ (I.e., $\widehat{fv}(0)=0$).

Comment: @DarioP. Yes I know what happens when we consider the zero modes. I am not talking about uniqueness here; I am just talking about solvability. This problem comes from a more general one with zero modes fixed (or under control). So that would give me no problem.

Comment: Ok, but you have to add conditions that ensures the solution not to be trivial. As stated you always have existence of solutions, since $v\equiv 0$ is a solution for any $f$.